# Why is one of my posts prefixed with "Next Post" on Google search

Tags: next-post-link, google-search

I run a website on WordPress.org and at the bottom of each post are two links that point to the previous and next post. I was doing a Google search on one of my website's posts and it showed two results one that just shows the title and another that shows the same title but prefixed with "next post". Both results have the same Url and meta description--because they are the same thing.

Why is this happening? I tried to google the problem but nothing showed up. I'm concerned because it can lead to Google thinking that I have duplicated content. Also, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hi, have to tried to use `schema.org`? You can define the start, end and navigations using schematics, so google will know which part of your page is content, and which part is a link to the next post.

Comment: @JackJohansson Actually, I don't know how to do that. Would it help if I use the html nav tag instead?

Comment: That might help, however the `nav` tag wasn't designed exactly to communicate with search engines. If you take a look at schema.org, you will find various examples with fully explained implementation guide. This will also increase your seo score and ranking.